# how to prepare one-to-many relationship with dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a dataset returning two tables with stored procedure; the first one is in a one-to-one relationship with inner join.

My second table is the items table marked with the id column in the first table.

Table1.ID is kept in Def_SpecificationID column

Stored procedure code:

```
SELECT Spec.ID as SpecID,
       Spec.Def_Specification_GroupID,
       Spec.SpecTitle,
       Spec.HasItem,
       Spec.IsActive,
       SpecGroup.SpecGroup
FROM Def_Specification Spec
INNER JOIN Def_Specification_Group SpecGroup ON Spec.Def_Specification_GroupID = SpecGroup.ID
WHERE Spec.IsActive = 1

SELECT ID, Def_SpecificationID, SpecificationTitle 
FROM Def_Specification_Items
```

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qosru.png)

What I want to do here is to add data to the elements of the first table according to the Def Specification ID in the second table.

Entity

```
   public class DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems
   {
        public DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems()
        {
            this.DefSpecificationItems = new();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Def_Specification_GroupID { get; set; }
        public string SpecTitle { get; set; }
        public int HasItem { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string SpecGroup { get; set; }
        public List<DefSpecificationItems> DefSpecificationItems { get; set; }
    }
```

Dapper code

```
await connection.QueryAsync<DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems,DefSpecificationItems, DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems>(
                    "SP_DEF_SPECIFICATION_GET_ALL_BY_ACTIVE", 
                    (spec,items)=> {
                        DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems result=new();
                        result.DefSpecificationItems.Add(items);
                        return result;
                    },
                    new { Active = active },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    splitOn: "Def_SpecificationID,SpecID"
                    );
```

This code worked for me but is there a dapper version of it

```
var specification = new List<DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems>();
                    using (var multi = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync("SP_DEF_SPECIFICATION_GET_ALL_BY_ACTIVE", new { Active = active },
                        commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure))
                    {
                        var specs =(await multi.ReadAsync<DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems>()).ToList();
                        var specItems = (await multi.ReadAsync<DefSpecificationItems>()).ToList();

                        foreach (var item in specs)
                        {
                            item.DefSpecificationItems = specItems.Where(i => i.Def_SpecificationID == item.ID).ToList();
                            
                        }
                        specification = specs;
                    }
```

How can I map tables returned from dataset in dapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Def_Specification_Items 
WHERE Def_SpecificationId = @DefSpecificationId;
```

`@DefSpecificationId` will be parameter passed to *Dapper*:

```cs
        specs.DefSpecificationItems = await connection
            .QueryAsync<List<DefSpecificationItems>>(sql, new 
            {
                DefSpecificationId = specs.Id
            });
```

`specs` is `DefSpecificationAndGroupAndItems` here

Comment: thank you but this is not the answer to my question, it is not mapping. If you examine the code blocks above, you can see a similar method.